# Show Current Date Time in HTML Input Type

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to show the Current Date and Time in HTML input type, which i am saving in database.

My current code is:

```
<?php 
$date = date('Y-m-d H:i s'); 
<input type="datetime-local" name="date" value="' .$date. '">
?>
```

The code works if show date only. But whenever i set time it doesn't work.

Comment: This is not valid PHP code. Did you remove an `echo` or something?

Comment: my bad. actually i just copied two lines from a big one. But what i want to show remains same

Answer (score 2):

If your code is actually what it is, then you need to clean it up, because it's not valid PHP first of all.

```
<?php $date = date('Y-m-d\TH:i'); ?>
<input type="datetime-local" name="date" value="<?= $date ?>">
```

PHP code must be separate from HTML Elements. So the first PHP block assigns `$date`, and the second PHP block uses a [short echo](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) syntax to output the value of that PHP variable inline.

**Edit:** Since you're looking for the current time, you should print your datetime value in an appropriate format. I've adjusted this for you based on the [PHP date format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) and [datetime-local input value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#Value).

Comment: But still it doesnt show the current date and time in the html input tag